# How do I set MySQL host to something other than 'localhost' on ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I have two server bought and I have 2 real IP's. One for files and another for database. I setup mysql database to second server but I cannot connecting it from my first server because mysql hostname is localhost. How can I connect 2nd server database from first one?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like your question is more about server setup than about programming, and therefore it would possible be good to put it on https://serverfault.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IP Address of the Database server as the host name

i.e

```
host = '192.168.1.10`;
```

you will of course also have to make sure you are using a MySQL user account that is allowed to login from your applcation servers ip address

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your first server.
2. give below command on first server-

   mysql -h server_ip -u myuser -p

Here server_ip means 2nd db server ip, myuser is a db user for 2nd server.

Now it will ask password so give your db server password for root user.

Note: Make sure myuser should have privileges on 2nd db server either from 1st server or should have global privileges.